# Help : Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly using SQLIte

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sqlite, reference, elmah

One of my projects uses Elmah, which references SQLite. Elmah is built against SQLite for .Net version 1.0.44.0

well I was experimenting with some 64 bit stuff (my dev box is 32 bit) so I needed the 64 bit version of SQLite for .Net. I grabbed the latest build of it (1.0.51.0 at the time) and used their installer to install it.
For my 32 bit project, I updated the reference to System.Data.SQLite to point to the newer version.
Once I realized my mistake, I uninstalled it and grabbed the appropriate original version, and pointed my reference back to 1.0.44.0

Now when I build I get the warning about different versions of the same dependant assembly. Clicking on it asks if I want it to edit my app.config and it inserts this:

```
<runtime>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="DB937BC2D44FF139" culture="neutral"/>
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.51.0" newVersion="1.0.51.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

umm..I don't have 1.0.51.0 installed or existing anywhere on my system anymore! where is the conflict? why does visual studio think it exists somewhere? I checked in the GAC and there is no System.Data.SQLite anywhere.

I'd like to get rid of this annoying warning.
I have another project in the same solution that also references SQLite, but I never updated the reference to the newer version (and subsequently never changed the reference back)..it has always been referencing 1.0.44.0.  That project doesn't complain at all...

Answer (score 0):

Use ildasm.exe to look at the manifests in your app and assemblies.

Comment: I did..the only thing that references SQLite is Elmah..and it's asking for 1.0.44.0...not 1.0.51.0...
Nothing in my project/solution is asking for that newer version..but visual studio is still complaining...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a utility to help identify the offending reference(s):

http://www.brianlow.com/index.php/2010/01/25/find-conflicting-assembly-references/

Comment: Link is broken, I really want this tool!